# Change button for color input modes

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, buttons, color, desktop-application

I have this SWT widget (color picker) with label:

[image]

By pressing the star button, color picker field transforms into code field, where you can write code:

[image]

I am not satisfied with this "star button", which is used to change input mode for color.
I think there are should be some alternative, how this could be done. But I can't think of any other application with the same functionality. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If I want a custom colour, I have to select the star, and then enter in the colour value.  You are **adding an extra step for no benefit**, and adding something that is not very clear.

I would instead treat the **dropdown as a shortcut** to a defined colour which modifies a text field which can represent a **hex colour**, or a **code colour**.

That way it is clean and simple to use, and makes it as fast as possible.

Here is an mockup of what I mean:

[image]

If you have the ability, I would also make the colour block a link to a **colour palette** with relevant colours.  This would also act as a shortcut to change the hex value or code value depending on what is most applicable.  Something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my mistake - I explained what I want to do in a very brief way. I can't go away from code field, this is the domain-specific area of app. It must be there. Also there are other different GUI elements: width pickers, style pickers, text editors and so on that will have two  different input modes. Color is the only example. Hence, I need this "trigger" to switch on the "input code mode". What is the most intuitive way for end-user to perform it? End-users are aware of code input and app functionality.

Comment: @Steve could you please explain how the 4th example shown would not work? You could just not use hex codes, but keep the text area for domain specific code.

Comment: yes, you are right about 4th example. But since this two colors could be different, it would be too confusing

Comment: @Steve How could two be different?

Comment: design time / runtime

Comment: @Steve I still don't follow. The dropdown and colour picker act as selectors that modify the free text field, and only the free text field is used for the output.  How could you have two different ones in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the dropdown box editable, then when the user starts typing the control suggests colors from the list. For advanced users the box should accept color values in hex.